# Arithmetic Progressions containing integers close to a power of 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider an arithmetic progression of the form $\{kq: k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, where $q$ is an odd integer. Do such APs always contain a number of the form $2^n \pm 1$?

I was initially interested in the largest $K(q)$ for which $\{kq: 0 \leq k < K(q)\}$ didn't contain a number of the form $2^n \pm 1$. Then I realized that I couldn't even prove $K(q)$ is always finite.

I wrote a small python code to check the $K(q)$ numbers for the first 30 odd numbers. The distribution is interesting.

```
1    1 
3    1 
5    1
7    1
9    1
11   3
13   5
15   1
17   1
19   27
21   3
23   89
25   41
27   19
29   565
31   1
33   1
35   117
37   7085
39   105
41   25
43   3
45   91
47   178481
49   42799
51   5
53   1266205
55   19065
57   9
59   9099507
61   17602325
63   1
65   1
```

K(67) however is at least 100 million.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem. -- But this is not research level ... .

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't thinking clearly :-)
Fermat's little theorem does the trick, and so does the proof by Julian below.

We also get that if p is a prime such that (p-1)/2 is a prime, then K(p) is $2^{(p-1)/2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question can be rephrased as follows:

> Given $q\in\mathbb{N}$, $q$ odd, does there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
>   $q$ divides $2^n+1$ or $2^n-1$?

The answer is yes. Let $q\in\mathbb{N}$ be odd. Consider the set
$$
P=\{2+1,2^2+1,\dots,2^q+1\}.
$$
If $q$ divides some element in $P$ there is nothing to prove. If not, by the Pigeon Hole Principle, there exist $1\le m<n\le q$ such that $2^m+1$ and $2^n+1$ have the same remainder when divided by $q$, that is,
$$
2^m+1\equiv 2^n+1\pmod q.
$$
Then $q$ divides $2^n-2^m=2^m(2^{n-m}-1)$. Since $q$ is odd, $q$ must divide $2^{n-m}-1$.

Comment: Of course $q$ being odd will not divide anything in $P$...

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz I meant $2^k+1$. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It works the other way as well.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $67$ will divide $2^e\pm 1$ for a divisor $1,3,11$ or $33$ of $\frac{67-1}{2}$. Since $3$ is too small and $2^{11}=2048=30\cdot67+38$ we have with rounding $$K(67) \approx \frac{2^{33}}{67}=128,207,978.98.$$ Evidently $$2^{33}+1=67\cdot(128,207,979)$$

To independently verify this use repeated squaring and doubling $\bmod{\ 67}$$$2^2=4,\ 2^4=16,\ 2^8=256=-12,\ 2^{16}=144=10,\ 2^{32}=100=33$$ and finally $$2^{33}=66=-1$$

One could also (to verify that no smaller power works) just keep multiplying by $2$ and reducing $\bmod\  67$ as shown at the end (where I might have stopped at $[33,66]=[33,-1]$)

Details: If $q=2e+1$ is an odd prime  then $q$ divides $2^{q-1}-1=2^{2e}-1=(2^e-1)(2^e+1).$ So $q$ divides one of those two factors and $K(q)\le\frac{2^e+1}{q}.$ In general for $q=p_1^{u_1}p_2^{u_2}\cdots$ the role of $q-1$ above is played by the least common multiple of the numbers $(p_1-1)p_1^{u_1-1},(p_2-1)p_2^{u_2-1},\cdots.$

We can also replace $2$ by some other base $b$ and simply require that $q$ is a number relatively prime to $b$.

---

powers of $2$ $\bmod\ 67$

[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 8], [4, 16], [5, 32], [6, 64=-3], [7, 61=-6], [8, 55], [9, 43], [10, 19], [11, 38], [12, 9], [13, 18], [14, 36], [15, 5], [16, 10], [17, 20], [18, 40], [19, 13], [20, 26], [21, 52], [22, 37], [23, 7], [24, 14], [25, 28], [26, 56], [27, 45], [28, 23], [29, 46], [30, 25], [31, 50], [32, 33], [33, **66=-1**], [34, 65], [35, 63], [36, 59], [37, 51], [38, 35], [39, 3], [40, 6], [41, 12], [42, 24], [43, 48], [44, 29], [45, 58], [46, 49], [47, 31], [48, 62], [49, 57], [50, 47], [51, 27], [52, 54], [53, 41], [54, 15], [55, 30], [56, 60], [57, 53], [58, 39], [59, 11], [60, 22], [61, 44], [62, 21], [63, 42], [64, 17], [65, 34], [66, 1]